# why is yslow not showing the page load time

Tags: performance, firefox, optimization, time, yslow

so I installed yslow firefox extension and it's on my statusbar...but it's not showing any page load time info and just says 'yslow' whenever I go to any page

do I have to do some configuration or something?

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [YSlow User Guide](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/help/) for a walk-through of using the Firefox extension.

If you're having trouble making the Firefox extension work, you can also try the [bookmarklet version](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/mobile/).

Answer (score 0):

Activate the Fire bug by hitting F12 key and after that you will be able to view the response time along with YSlow icon in status bar.